# Submenu issue in Child Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, submenu

**Hello,** my website link is: http://trueensan.com/

I have this small issue, that the drop down menu or (sub-menu) is just stuck on the page dropped and wont hide when I am not hovering over it (as you can see on the website the categories block) ... is there any thing I can modify in my style.css ??

- I was using the parent theme and I did not have this issue, but now after creating a child theme and using it, it just showed to me like that !!

Any Advises ??
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not sure just try with the following CSS.

```
 ul.menu li ul.submenu
 {
   display:none;
 }

 ul.menu li:hover ul.submenu
 {
   display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the code did not work on my style.css

BUT I figured it !!Thanks GOD!!

```
#navigation ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0; }
```

I changed the opacity from 1 to 0